# Substitute by Group in R

Tags: r, substitution, group

Can I do group-wide substitutions in a data frame in R? This is a very simplified version of my problem. I define three data frames as follows:

```
mature <- data.frame("mature_animals"=c("horse", "dog", "cat"))
young <- data.frame("young_animals"=c("foal", "pup", "kitten"))
animals <- data.frame("animal_list"=c("horse", "cat", "cat", "horse", "dog",
                                      "horse", "dog", "dog", "cat"))
```

For each 'mature' animal in 'animals' I would like to substitute the corresponding young animal in 'young'. So I would like 'animals' to end up as c("foal", "kitten", "kitten", "foal", "pup", "foal", "pup", "pup", "kitten").

I can achieve this readily enough by looping over the contents of 'animals' one by one:

```
n_animal <- nrow(animals)
for(i in 1:n_animal){
  j <- which(mature$mature_animals==animals$animal_list[i])
  animals$animal_list[i] <- young$young_animals[j]
}
```

But that get slower as 'animals' get longer. Can I take advantage of grouping in any way - obviously there are far fewer groups than individual entries?

Thank you,
MGL.

Comment: Are we to assume equal lengths of young and mature as well as correctly ordered as in example above?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is with `match()`:

```
animals$animal_list <- young[match(animals$animal_list, mature$mature_animals), 1]
animals$animal_list
# [1] "foal"   "kitten" "kitten" "foal"   "pup"    "foal"   "pup"    "pup"    "kitten"
```

The `match` function returns the index of the matching value and we can use that index to identify the new value.